# AngularStrap bs-dropdown with the "hover" trigger doesn't stay open long enough

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

When using the bs-dropdown with the "hover" trigger, the menu doesn't stay visible long enough to allow the user to click on a menu item:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Fi39BdCOqHXnPAgITD01?p=preview

Using a delay makes it behave in unexpected ways:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2Q63DDJEyP9CTPMUfYD?p=preview

Ideally the dropdown should stay up as long as the mouse is on the menu, and disappear when the mouse leaves the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `hover` pseudoevent's `mouseleave` gets triggered when you hover out of the button to focus on the actual dropdown. Instead you can try providing the container as `button` itself. Example

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-lg btn-primary myButton" 
        bs-dropdown="dropdown" 
        data-container=".myButton">Hover to toggle dropdown</button>
```

Here i added `data-container` as `myButton` which is the class i gave for the same button.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cnW46mRLGKgSNo0jtKUF?p=preview)**

Using delay on hide is of no effect since the hide will eventually happen after the specified delay as the animation gets queued, as you hover out of the button and is going to hide after the delay so you should expect the user to be quick enough to select the dropdown option. But as a work around you can just use container till there is a fix provided for this.

Comment: Thank you! This works. The animation 'animation-flipX' causes a bug where the dropdown will sometimes get stuck in the open position. But removing the animation fixes it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See this issue for tracking the progress of this issue:

[bs-dropdown and trigger hover #638](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/638)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to implement a dropdown on a bootstrapped nav bar.
After reading the linked github issue in Blade1336's response I added `data-container="self"`. This **did** make the dropdown visible long enough to click on the dropdown items. Unfortunately, after adding it the menu dropdown items were no longer clickable. `data-container="self"` also resulted in a slightly wonky ui experience. My code looked like this:

```
<li data-match-route="/config*">  
   <a bs-dropdown="configDropdown" data-trigger="hover" data-container="self">Config</a>
</li>
```

I ended up switching around the tags and placing the bs-dropdown in my `<li>` tag instead which gave me the desired functionality (my links are clickable again). My code now looks like this:

```
<li data-match-route="/config*" bs-dropdown="configDropdown" data-trigger="hover" data-container="self">
   <a>Config</a>
</li>
```

*I kept the `<a>` tag just for styling purposes