# AngularStrap data-container="self" not working on Firefox

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am trying to use hover to show dropdown / popover and use `data-container="self"` to make the dropdown / popover stay appear when mouse moved to it. This method works on Google Chrome but not on Firefox.

Example Code:

```
<button type="button" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover | click" data-delay="300" bs-dropdown="dropdown" data-container="self">Click to toggle dropdown</button>
```

How can I get it works on firefox?

Comment: Do you have any plunkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: does it work if you omit the `data-`? use the attribute the way it's defined in the code as `container=`?

Comment: I think there is already logged issue, & i think its by you only https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1419

Answer (score 1):

I never heard of the `self` keyword as the container parameter in angular-strap. Where does it come from?

Anyway, here, `container` is useful if you want to append the dropdown to another element. Since it does not seem to be your case, simply do not provide `data-container`, and the dropdown will be appended to the element itself.

EDIT:

Okay, so, I tried, and saw the problem you are describing. You could try the solution given here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21293850/4506790): add a specific class to your button, and give it in data-container.

```
<button type="button"
        class="dropdown-btn"
        data-placement="right"
        data-trigger="hover"
        data-delay="300"
        bs-dropdown="dropdown"
        data-container=".dropdown-btn">
    Hover to toggle dropdown
</button>
```